# How to Trigger AWS Lambda(Python) when a message arrives in the SQS,delete the message from the queue after processing?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

How to trigger AWS Lambda function(Python) when a message arrives in the SQS, and pass the message to an HTTP Endpoint, after processing the data in the API, delete the message from the SQS queue? How can I achieve this inside the Python lambda?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a [SQS trigger](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-sqs.html) on a Lambda function to process the messages off the queue. If the function successfully processes the messages in a batch without any errors, they are deleted from the queue with the right [permissions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-sqs.html#events-sqs-permissions).

Comment: How can I handle the situation if the function is calling an HTTP endpoint and if the result is false, and I still want the message to be active in the queue, instead of not deleting the message only if there is exception?

Comment: If the function errors out - for any reason, the message will not be deleted from the queue; but rather stays under it's [Visibility Timeout](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-visibility-timeout.html), stays hidden until the timeout expires and remains visible for Lambda to grab them again and process it.

The messages from the queue are only deleted if they are successfully processed, or if the Message Retention period expires.